# button is not working when i click on button arrow it is not taking me to the next image

Tags: html, css

```
<section id="carouselExampleControls">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>You no longer have to carry a portable oxygen meter while at home.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image"
            src="C:\Users\adharsh.mamidi\Desktop\webdevelopment\oxyhome\TinDog-Start-master\images\second image.jpg" alt="Portable-oxygen">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">OxyHome provides the same amount of concentration as of the portable machine. Breathe.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-image"
            src="C:\Users\adharsh.mamidi\Desktop\webdevelopment\oxyhome\TinDog-Start-master\images\lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" role="button" href="#carouselExampleControls" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>
```

IThe buttons are created but when i click on the next button im not getting the next image the buttons are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `data-ride` attribute and replacing it with `data-interval="false"` or `data-ride="carousel"`